# Positioned Pseudo Does Not Work with a Doctype

Tags: css, html

From my previous question: [Adding Doctype Destroys Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588958/adding-doctype-destroys-layout) I figured out that the `right:-10;` statement in:

```
#nav li:after {
    width:10px;
    content:"";
    background: url('tabRight.png');
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    right:-10;  /*HERE*/
}
```

completely messes up my tab menu layout **with** an added doctype. If I remove that statement or set `right:0;` everything is fixed and the doctype stays in place. There is a small problem however, shifting the right image over to the right 10 pixels is what made my "closing-doors" technique work. This is because the right sliding door has a **transparent** background and when the doors are "closed" the right shift apparently didn't let the transparency be obscured by the left door. The picture below hopefully describe things better.

[image]

The blue border is the right door, the red is the **li** element, the green is the **ul** element. The second picture shows the right shift done with the :after pseudo. Is there any way to fix this issue, or does anyone know a simple technique around this? The html code is in my previous question up above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not using [CSS gradients](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and `border-radius` to style your tabs? Apparently your method has got the potential to unleash tons of errors depending on which browser (version) you are using and whatever doctype you're declaring. :/

Comment: @Harti, I'm very new to web development so I didn't know about these things. I'm taking a look now at the link you posted and looking into it. Do you have any additional advice for me because I've already found some of it really helpful on the border-radius topic. How would Gradients work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units are required in standards mode. Use `right: -10px;`.

Comment: Unbelievable, that was ridiculous...  More than 6 hours googling alternatives to sliding doors and checking doctype standards. Thank you very much that was incredibly helpful. Now I've got to go get a bandaid because I made my pinky bleed as I hit the mouse after seeing it work.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you have to use unit measurements. There are a variety of measurements you can use in your case you want to use: `right: 10px;`

And a side note, Doctypes are important and not important at the same time. They help the browser server your HTML in the correct way. So be sure to know the standards of the (X)HTML language you are writing in to avoid having strange quirks.